# In Minecraft, why does blocks have a delay between dropping a item when broken?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started a new world in survival. I went to gather wood, but when I broke a log in a tree, it flashed then dropped the log after a few seconds. I'm mot lagging and bugs never became an issue for me.

Comment: Which version are you using? Even though you said it isn't, "block lag", as this is called, is usually caused by lag. This is most common on a server.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between player-lag (client-side) and block-lag, you can be running 60+ fps easily and get lots of block-lag.

The problem usually comes up in multi-player servers, where your computer is simply not catching up to the animations being done in minecraft. Or it could be latency, essentially internet-lag. If your playing single-player which I assume is correct, make sure you turn off "open to LAN". Another probability is that your seed save is corrupted. Try re-making a minecraft world.